# Is there an app for the StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Is there an app for the StackExchange sites? More specifically the Arqade? If there isn't consider creating one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, one for [Android](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/) and one for [iOS](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/) (sorry, Windows Phone).  It covers the entire network, but not chat.  Although there is [ChatSEy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tommedley.chatsey) for Android from our very own fredley.

Comment: Shame really... a lot of people that I know, including myself, use Windows phone.

Answer (score 2):

[For Android.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)